# BigQuery Subqueries

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to BQ. My objective is to create a query which will drill down to specific values.

The following query displays iam roles, such as ServiceAccountUser or serviceAccountTokenCreator.

```
SELECT name, iam.role AS roles, (ARRAY_TO_STRING(iam.members, "")) AS members
  FROM dataset_blah_7553a5b37_Project,
  UNNEST (iam_policy.bindings) AS iam
  GROUP by name, roles, members
  HAVING role = 'roles/iam.serviceAccountUser' OR role = 'roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator'
```

It displays for example the following:

```
Row            name                                          roles                                 members
1 //cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/1234567890  roles/iam.ServiceAccountUser                 serviceAccount:xyz321@blah.com
2 //cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/1234567890  roles/iam.ServiceAccountUser                 user:  ericcartman@blah.com
3 //cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/1234567890  roles/iam.ServiceAccountTokenCreator         group: gcp-blah-group001@blah.com
4 //cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/1234567890  roles/iam.ServiceAccountUser                 user:  stanmarshn@blah.com
5 //cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/1234567890  roles/iam.ServiceAccountUser                 serviceAccount:abc1234@blah.com
6 //cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/1234567890  roles/iam.ServiceAccountUser                 serviceAccount:opr3234@blah.com
7 //cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/1234567890  roles/iam.ServiceAccountUser                 serviceAccount:stu2224@blah.com
```

However, I need to drill down further to filter only "group:" and "user:", such as

```
group: gcp-blah-001@blah.com
user:  ericcartman@blah.com
```

How can I accomplish it? Subqueries?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can do filtering using subqueries in bigquery. [1]

You can try something like

```
SELECT table1.name, table1.roles, table1.members
FROM(SELECT name, iam.role AS roles, (ARRAY_TO_STRING(iam.members, "")) AS members
     FROM dataset_blah_7553a5b37_Project,
     UNNEST (iam_policy.bindings) AS iam
     GROUP by name, roles, members
     HAVING role = 'roles/iam.serviceAccountUser' OR role = 
     'roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator') AS table1 
WHERE table1.members= "group: gcp-blah-001@blah.com" AND table1.members="user:  ericcartman@blah.com"
```

[1]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/subqueries#table_subquery_concepts

Comment: Thank you so much Dharman for your reply. Tried it. however, getting zero hits. I need to play with it, I guess. Thanks again!!!